# How do I check my comments?

Tags: support, comments

I made a comment on a post, and I have found some new information that would affect my comment. Is there a way to search for my comments? I can see a record of questions and answers, is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your username at the top of the page.
2. Select Activity in the menu bar.
3. Select Comments in the sub-menu.

[image]

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you.